# Running cloudprint service on boot - Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: server, printing, cloud

I'm currently running CUPS on Ubuntu Server 16.04. I've installed a printer which other computers on the network are able to see and print to.

I've been trying to print from outside my LAN using the google cloud print service, bearing in mind my printer is not cloud-ready. This is as far as I could get....

```
sudo apt-get install cloudprint
sudo apt-get update
```

Then all I need to run is....

```
sudo cloudprint
```

This seems to work great - while the session is active I'm able to print from any PC or directly from my Android phone.

However - as soon as I close the SSH session, the link to the cloud is dropped. Re-running the cloudprint command restores the connection. Is there any way I can have the service running in the background, starting at boot?

Thank you in advance!